# Minecraft PE/Windows 10 - can no longer recieve invites?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I open Minecraft PE, the friend I want to join is missing from the joinable friends list. I know he's online, and that all his settings line up, as do my own. I've investigated my Minecraft settings, xbox settings, phone settings and even wifi settings. From what I understand, everything seems to be set up to allow me to connect, but their world is missing. Other people can join his, and he can join mine, we can also both join other peoples' together. I've refreshed and restarted to no avail, and haven't been able to find any support for this issue. I just wanna play Minecraft with my bro :(

I've also tried all of the above on Minecraft Windows 10 edition. I was able to join my other friend's PE world from it, but not the first one.

LAN has always worked just fine, but when connecting via xbox live to this friend, it never cooperates.

Comment: Are you able to include anymore information? The phone in use, xbox live account types etc? There are many possible reasons.